# Automatic data record in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I receive the data on the P/E multiple in Google Sheets via GOOGLEFINANCE in the following manner:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOGL","pe")
```

How to write script in Google Sheets that would record the P/E values (or better the values of a particular cell) every day as at, say, 21:00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview).

You want to write a function that uses the [Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) to get the value of a given `Range` in a given `Sheet`, and then **append** that value in a new row on a different sheet.

You also want to set up a [time-based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to execute that function.

As an example, for a bound script with only one worksheet:

```
function copyA1toA2onSameSheet() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(
        sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()
    );
}
```

Note that `getActiveSheet` will always return the first sheet from a time-based trigger, as there is no UI instance. If you need a different sheet, consider `getSheetByName`, or using `getSheets()`.